# Let $a$,$b$ be arbitrary integers. Find $g$, also an integer, such that $\langle a \rangle$ $\cap$ $\langle b\rangle$ = $\langle g\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Notation: For any $a \in \mathbb Z$ we have $\langle a \rangle$  = {$na | n \in \mathbb Z$}.

I believe $g = a^Ib^L$ for $I,L \in \mathbb Z$

[This is an assignment, so please hints only.]

But I have no idea how to prove this, could I perhaps show that $\langle a \rangle$  $\cap$ $\langle b \rangle$  is a subgroup of $\langle g \rangle$  and vice versa? Am I right in thinking this way?

Comment: GCD could be of help.

Comment: I'm the \langle \rangle fairy, here to let you know that $\langle, \rangle$ plays nicer with TeX than <, > does :)

Comment: $g$ would have to be a multiple of $a$.

Comment: Why use `\bigcap` when `\cap` works?

Comment: There may be several things that are not done correctly, I apologise, my only reason is, I'm new to TeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\Bbb Z$ is principal ideal domain so $\langle a\rangle \cap \langle b\rangle=\langle g \rangle$. 
Now you must show that $g= l.c.m.(a,b)$.

---

$\textbf{Note:}$ It is also true for a finite element of integers. i.e., 
If $a_1,a_2,\cdots, a_n\in \Bbb Z$ then $\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{n}(a_i) =(a)$ and, $a=l.c.m(a_1,a_2\cdots, a_n)$

Comment: The lowest common multiple idea got me going (that's why I marked your answer as correct). I marked $g$ = lcm of $a$ and $b$, and since that is in $\mathbb Z$, the generator of it is a subgroup of the integers (considering only addition). Now clearly the generators of $a$ and $b$ are subgroups of the integers too. Moreover the intersection of any subgroups is a subgroup. Now I show what the generators are in set notation, and simply show these sets are subsets of each other. And so, they are equal. What do you think?

Comment: Just out of curiosity then, if $\langle a, b \rangle$ = $\langle h \rangle$, would I be onto something considering h = gcd of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: @FlorianSuess, You missed $\Bbb Z$ is principal ideal domain. It means that every ideal of $\Bbb Z$  is generated by one element. So, we have $\langle a, b \rangle=\langle g \rangle$ for some $g\in \Bbb Z$.